# Train Reward Model using Llama2:

Tags: deep-learning, llm, reward

this is my code that use to train reward model:

```
import os
import torch
from datasets import load_dataset,Dataset
from transformers import (
    AutoModelForCausalLM,
    AutoTokenizer,
    BitsAndBytesConfig,
    TrainingArguments,
    pipeline,
    logging,
    HfArgumentParser
)
import pandas as pd
from peft import LoraConfig, TaskType
from trl import RewardConfig, RewardTrainer

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
raw_dataset = Dataset.from_pandas(df[:3])

model_id = 'meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-hf'

compute_dtype = getattr(torch, "float16")

quant_config = BitsAndBytesConfig(
    load_in_4bit=True,
    bnb_4bit_quant_type="nf4",
    bnb_4bit_compute_dtype=compute_dtype,
    bnb_4bit_use_double_quant=False,
)

model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_id,use_auth_token=hf_auth)
model.config.use_cache = False
model.config.pretraining_tp = 1
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_id,use_auth_token=hf_auth)
tokenizer.add_special_tokens({'pad_token': '[PAD]'})
def formatting_func(examples):
    kwargs = {
        "padding": "max_length",
        "truncation": True,
        "max_length": 256,
        "return_tensors": "pt"
    }

    # Prepend the prompt and a line break to the chosen and rejected responses.
    prompt_plus_chosen_response = examples["prompt"] + "\n" + examples["chosen"]
    prompt_plus_rejected_response = examples["prompt"] + "\n" + examples["rejected"]
    

    # Tokenize the modified fields.
    tokens_chosen = tokenizer.encode_plus(prompt_plus_chosen_response, **kwargs)
    tokens_rejected = tokenizer.encode_plus(prompt_plus_rejected_response, **kwargs)

    return {
        "input_ids": tokens_chosen["input_ids"][0],
        "attention_mask": tokens_chosen["attention_mask"][0],
        "labels": tokens_rejected["input_ids"][0],  # Use rejected as labels for causal LM
        "input_ids_chosen": tokens_chosen["input_ids"][0],
        "attention_mask_chosen": tokens_chosen["attention_mask"][0],
        "input_ids_rejected": tokens_rejected["input_ids"][0],
        "attention_mask_rejected": tokens_rejected["attention_mask"][0],
    }
raw_datasets = raw_dataset.map(formatting_func)

OUTPUT_DIR = "/kaggle/working/"
training_args = RewardConfig(
           output_dir=OUTPUT_DIR,
    num_train_epochs=10,
    per_device_train_batch_size=4,
    gradient_accumulation_steps=1,
    optim="paged_adamw_32bit",
    save_steps=25,
    logging_steps=25,
    learning_rate=2e-4,
    weight_decay=0.001,
    fp16=False,
    bf16=False,
    max_grad_norm=0.3,
    max_steps=-1,
    warmup_ratio=0.03,
    group_by_length=True,
    lr_scheduler_type="constant",
    no_cuda=False,
    report_to="wandb",
    run_name="reward_model",
    )

peft_config = LoraConfig(
    task_type=TaskType.SEQ_CLS,
    inference_mode=False,
    r=8,
    lora_alpha=32,
    lora_dropout=0.1,
)

 trainer = RewardTrainer(
        model=model,
        tokenizer=tokenizer,
        args=training_args,
        train_dataset=raw_datasets,
        peft_config=peft_config,
        #  max_length=None
    )

trainer.train()
```

This code gives IndexError: index out of range in self in google colab.
And im also use Kaggle notebooks with T4x2. I cannot load this models in boths GPU's
Can anyone tell me what is the issue??

Kaggle:
RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered
CUDA kernel errors might be asynchronously reported at some other API call, so the stacktrace below might be incorrect.
For debugging consider passing CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1.
Compile with `TORCH_USE_CUDA_DSA` to enable device-side assertions.

I load this model into the CPU without quantization. Then it shows:

IndexError: index out of range in self

Comment: Have you tried doing what the error message suggest and run it with `CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1`?

Comment: I'm using Kaggle notebooks. I don't know how to do that.

Comment: The diagnostic **told** you to setenv CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1. I don't understand why the error you're sharing with us isn't from an execution environment where that env var was set. You know there is a specific problem. You know there is a specific means of diagnosing that problem. Internet strangers can't set that env var for you. You can. What's missing from the path forward toward a technical solution? Is there some additional piece of advice you're hoping to solicit from us? You can run a python kernel locally. With env var settings of your choosing. Choose the default. Or a better choice.

Comment: i have tried using  os.environ['CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING'] = "1" but still getting error:
RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered
Compile with `TORCH_USE_CUDA_DSA` to enable device-side assertions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is solved.

The issue is max_length. when lower value used to max_length this issue is not occurs. that means 30GB gpu not enogh to for this process.